# Callback on scrollTop

Tags: jquery

```
$("html").scrollTop($(document).height(),function(){
    $("#page_jump_input").focus();
});
```

I can't get a callback function to work on the method `scrollTop()`.

The scrolling works, but the callback wont. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could solve your problem

```
$('html').animate({
   scrollTop: $(document).height()
}, function(){
   $("#page_jump_input").focus();
});
```

It uses jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) as `scrollTop()` has no callback function.