# jQuery - Getting DOM element that does not load until you scroll

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to access an HTML element that does not actually generate until you scroll down in the page.

Therefore, code like this returns nil

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var city = $('.pv-entity__location').text()
});
```

How can I use jQuery to make sure the full page is loaded / scroll to the bottom upon loading before retrieving this variable?

**Update:** 
I tried to have jQuery scroll the page and then retrieve the variable, it doesn't seem to work. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 9999 }, function() {
        var city = $('.pv-entity__location').text()
        console.log(`Text: ${city}`)
    });
});
```

**Update 2**

Figured out the solution with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692118/callback-on-scrolltop), I needed to set a callBack function on j`animate()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, function(){
        var city = $('.pv-entity__location:first:last-child').text().trim()
        console.log(`Text: ${city || "empty"}`)
    });

    //});
});
```

Comment: Same problem as pulling  money out of the bank before you put some in..there's none there

Comment: If it's not generated yet, you can't access it. What do you want to do with it before it's generated?

Comment: Sorry I did not ask this question clearly, I will rephrase- how can I use jQuery to make sure the full page is loaded / scroll to the bottom upon loading before retrieving this variable?

Comment: There is text inside that element that will be used for something else

Comment: Show us the code that loads more on scrolling. Would want to check after more is loaded. Sounds like a design flaw if you need it right away when page loads

Comment: It depends on how you're dynamically loading the elements. Some only load an element when you scroll to the specific part of the page where it lives. So you'd need to know the containing DIV where it will be loaded. Then you can use `.scrollTo()` to go there.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm actually building a Chrome extension to scrape content from a user's profile when visited. It's not my website's content

Comment: @Barmar I tried you're suggestion but I think I did something wrong. I'll update my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692118/callback-on-scrolltop), I needed to set a callBack function on `animate()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, function(){
        var city = $('.pv-entity__location:first:last-child').text().trim()
        console.log(`Text: ${city} || "empty"}`)
    });

    //});
});
```